# Getting a "There are no focusable elements inside the <FocusTrap />" error inside next.js app

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, recoiljs, headless-ui

I am trying to run this code but getting this error, I want to create a button that opens a headless UI. I have tried to add the ref and initialFocus but it did not help, I have also tried to copy the code from the headless UI modal example and put it inside the Feed component but it did not work also

#### Index.js

```
export default function Home({ providers }) {
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  const [commentModal, setCommentModal] = useRecoilState(commentModalState);

  const sendData = async () => {
    setDoc(doc(db, "users", session.user.uid), {
      id: session.user.uid,
      name: session.user.realname,
      username: session.user.username,
      email: session.user.email,
      last_updated: serverTimestamp(),
    });
  };

  if (!session) return <Login providers={providers} />;
  return (
    
    <div className={`${sendData()}`}>
      <Feed/>
      <Modal/>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const providers = await getProviders();
  const session = await getSession(context);

  return {
    props: {
      providers,
      session,
    },
  };
}
```

#### Feed.js

```
function Feed() {
  const [commentModal, setCommentModal] = useRecoilState(commentModalState);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        class="relative p-0.5 inline-flex items-center justify-center font-bold overflow-hidden group rounded-md"
        onClick={() => {
          setCommentModal(true);
        }}
      >
        <span class="w-full h-full bg-gradient-to-br from-[#ff8a05] via-[#ff5478] to-[#ff00c6] group-hover:from-[#ff00c6] group-hover:via-[#ff5478] group-hover:to-[#ff8a05] absolute"></span>
        <span class="relative px-6 py-3 transition-all ease-out bg-gray-900 rounded-md group-hover:bg-opacity-0 duration-400">
          <span class="relative text-white">POST</span>
        </span>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Feed;
```

#### Modal.js

```
function Modal() {
  const [commentModal, setCommentModal] = useRecoilState(commentModalState);

  return (
    <Transition.Root show={commentModal} as={Fragment}>
      <Dialog
        as="div"
        className="fixed z-50 inset-0 pt-8"
        onClose={setCommentModal}
      >
        <div className="flex items-start justify-center min-h-[800px] sm:min-h-screen pt-4 px-4 pb-20 text-center sm:block sm:p-0">
          <Transition.Child
            as={Fragment}
            enter="ease-out duration-300"
            enterFrom="opacity-0"
            enterTo="opacity-100"
            leave="ease-in duration-200"
            leaveFrom="opacity-100"
            leaveTo="opacity-0"
          >
            <Dialog.Overlay className="fixed inset-0 bg-[#5b7083] bg-opacity-100 transition-opacity" />
          </Transition.Child>

          <Transition.Child
            as={Fragment}
            enter="ease-out duration-300"
            enterFrom="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
            enterTo="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
            leave="ease-in duration-200"
            leaveFrom="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
            leaveTo="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
          >
            <div>
            </div>
          </Transition.Child>
        </div>
      </Dialog>
    </Transition.Root>
  );
}

export default Modal;
```